# Retrieving document by ID with Stargate Document API returns error 404, "A document with the id ... does not exist"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

I have created a database in datastax and create a collection and its document. It gave me a documentID to list my collections or the data inside the document, now when i go to get the document by inserting appropriate fields and also paste document id as required, it is giving me Error 404 that document with this document id does not exist.

[image: this is the screenshot of creating the document]

[image: this is the documentID i got after executing]

[image: This is my entered field while getting the document and the error is in the documentID i guess]

[image: This is my error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've enclosed the document ID in double quotes (`"`) when you specified it in the Swagger UI:

```
document-id: "ae7362d3-8571-4a97-a639-69961e07c59f"
```

As a result, the quotes (`"`) are getting encoded as `%22` in the URL and replaces the document ID as `%22ae7362d3-8571-4a97-a639-69961e07c59f%22`.

You should supply the document ID on its own without the double quotes and you should be able to retrieve it with the API call:

```
document-id: ae7362d3-8571-4a97-a639-69961e07c59f
```

For more info, see [Developing with Document API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-doc.html#_retrieving_a_specified_document). Cheers!